# mongodb containing multiple grouped queries

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection, XYZ that contains

```
Year Month Value  
2019 1     AA  
2019 2     AB  
2020 1     A  
2020 2     B  
2020 3     C
```

What I want to do is something like this in SQL, which basically making two groups of "and" queries

```
SELECT * 
  FROM XYZ 
 WHERE (Year >= 2019 and Month >= 3)  and (Year <= 2020 and Month <= 2)
```

So I translated to this, but it produces nothing.

```
db.XYZ.find({
    $and: 
[
     {$and: [ { Year: {$gte: 2019} }, { Month: { $gte:3 } } ]},
     {$and: [ { Year: {$lte: 2020} }, { Month: { $lte:2 } } ]}
]    
})
```

I expect mongodb to return, but right now it returns no records:

```
- 2020 1 A
- 2020 2 B
```

Comment: There will never be a `Month` that is both greater than 3 and less than 2.

Comment: Thanks Joe, you are right not in a single year there won't be, but for a different year there might be.

For example, with the above condition (gte 2019 Mar (3) AND lte 2020 Mar (2)); 
I expect mongodb to return:
2020 Jan (1), and 
2020 Feb (2)

Comment: But that's not what your logic statement evaluates to.  (A & B) & (C & D) == A & B & C & D.  So that query is for `Year >= 2019 AND Year <= 2020 AND Month <= 2 AND Month >= 3`  It is not possible for any document to ever match it.

Comment: Hi Joe, appreciate  your help. I can do this in SQL because I put the brackets around the grouped conditions. So, is there a mongodb syntax to cater for what I want to do? Aggregate, etc? I am not yet proficient with their syntax.

Comment: The SQL you have written doesn't work either, and least not in MySQL.  Was there an error copying the query into the question?

Comment: The SQL part is right when I copied it, but the mongodb part was not but I have edited it. What error did you get?

Comment: I created a table in MySQL with that data, and the select statement also didn't return any rows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210827/discussion-between-bluetoba-and-joe).

Answer (score 0):

Joe has basically answered my question:

the logic of my statement evaluates to: (A & B) & (C & D) ==> A & B & C & D

Therefore, the solutions are:
- aggregation queries, but could be inefficient for large number of records.
- create another field that takes the value of YYYYMM to perform query on.

Let me know if anyone-else have another opinion.

Could someone help how I could write the aggregation query? Fortunately for me, the table is first queried for a specific group of people, and therefore it is indexed. So performance is not so bad.

Answer (score 0):

One way to archive this is by using the aggregation framework, but it would be better to insert the data in a proper format in the first place.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      when: {
        $add: [
          {
            $multiply: [
              "$Year",
              100
            ]
          },
          "$Month"
        ]
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      when: {
        $gte: 201903,
        $lte: 202002
      }
    }
  },
])
```

which would return the following:

```
[
  {
    "Month": 1,
    "Value": "A",
    "Year": 2020,
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "when": 202001
  },
  {
    "Month": 2,
    "Value": "B",
    "Year": 2020,
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "when": 202002
  }
]
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/cDwIrKgY_M0

or

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      when: {
        $dateFromParts: {
          "year": "$Year",
          "month": "$Month"
        }
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      when: {
        $gte: ISODate("2019-03-01T00:00:00Z"),
        $lte: ISODate("2020-02-01T00:00:00Z"),
      }
    }
  },
])
```

which returns

```
[
  {
    "Month": 1,
    "Value": "A",
    "Year": 2020,
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "when": ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z")
  },
  {
    "Month": 2,
    "Value": "B",
    "Year": 2020,
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "when": ISODate("2020-02-01T00:00:00Z")
  }
]
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/d9r793JsqZ0

Comment: Why so complicated? Using date functions is perfect here.

Comment: @matthPen would you mind showing me how to do this? I have absolutely no clue. --- Oh, wow, you probably mean `$dateFromParts`, I didn't know it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with aggregagtion framework, transforming your data in date object before queryiing it properly :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      date: {
        $dateFromParts: {
          year: "$Year",
          month: "$Month"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $gt: [
              "$date",
              {
                $dateFromParts: {
                  year: 2019,
                  month: 3
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            $lte: [
              "$date",
              {
                $dateFromParts: {
                  year: 2020,
                  month: 2
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can test [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TkTexUE5ARE)